# How do i disable option which has multiple value separated by comma?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few select options with multiple values in it

```js
$('#addItemModal #servicesBlock select[name=service_id] option[value='+service.val()+']').prop('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<option value="26,30,31,32,34">01-10-2018 to 05-12-2018</option>
```

I want to disable the option using value by jQuery

My current code worked fine for single-valued options, but I need to change it now to hold multiple values?

It throws exception as below

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #addItemModal #servicesBlock select[name=service_id] option[value=26,30,31,32,34]

Comment: try quotes `$('#servicesBlock select[name=service_id] option[value="'+service.val()+'"]')
.prop('disabled', true);` or $.map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[value=]` attribute selector expects the value to be within quotation marks: `[vale="some_value"]`. The following should therefore work:

```
$('#addItemModal #servicesBlock select[name=service_id] option[value="'+service.val()+'"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

Though the [JavaScript backtick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) could be useful to make the code a little more readable (if your clients have support for it):

```
$(`#addItemModal #servicesBlock select[name=service_id] option[value="${ service.val() }"]`).prop('disabled', true);
```